# Remove a drawn object in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I have created a Windows Form, in which I am drawing 3 objects(Rectangle, Circle, and Line). I have 1 base class for all of them and separate classes for each of the objects. All objects are stored in an array.

In Windows Form has been created a Panel in which  we draw and 3 buttons to draw an object.

What I need is to select an object with a mouse click and highlight it, then with pressing the fourth button to delete it.

The problem is I don't know how to select the object which has been clicked...
Any guides or piece of code, how to do it?

Comment: The idea is to always redraw the surface.  Removing a part is to simply stop drawing it.  You can redraw the entire visible region or just a part of it.

Comment: Yes, but how to figure out which object was clicked and wherein the array is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

On your onClick event cast the sender parameter in your Object type something like this:

ObjectBeingClicked objectName = (ObjectBeingClicked)sender;

Or another example:

Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)sender;